# TypeError: "setting getter-only property vuejs axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

What am I trying to do: 
Take an image as input. Convert it into a base64 string. Prepare payload containing the base64 string and hit the backend with that post request. Get the response data, preview the base64 image from the response object.

When I run the code, I get following error inside axios request:

> TypeError: "setting getter-only property "result""

FYI, `console.log(response)` prints successfully and I can see the response data. 
However, `console.log('SUCCESSFUL')` doesn't print due to error

```
<template>
  <div id="Uploader">
    <input type="file" id="file" ref="file" v-on:change="handleFileChanges" multiple/>
    <button v-on:click="upload_picture">Submit</button>
    <div> Hello {{result}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios';


export default {
  name: 'Uploader',

  data() {
    return {
      file: '',
      values: '',
      result: [],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    handleFileUpload() {
      [this.file] = this.$refs.file.files;
    },
    handleFileChanges(e) {
      const reader = new window.FileReader(); // if window i
      // s not used it says File READER is not defined
      reader.onload = function oldyfunt(event) {
        // dispatch fileAttached to state UI postEditor with event.target.result as read dataURL
        this.values = event.target.result;
        console.log('VALUES');
        console.log(this.values);
        const data = {
          images: {
            image1: this.values.split(',')[1],
          },
        };
        axios.post('http://0.0.0.0:9094/analyze',
          data,
          {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          }).then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.result = response.data;
          console.log('SUCCESS!!');
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          console.log('FAILURE!!');
        });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    },
    upload_picture() {
      console.log(this.values);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change

```
reader.onload = function oldyfunt(event) {
```

by

```
reader.onload = (event) => {
```

it should fix your problem

`this` refer to current scope, in your case `this` refer to `oldyfunt` function not `vue instance`

you can go deeper for `arrow function` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: this fixed it. Thanks! Does this mean **this** inside arrow function refers to the current scope and when using function, the scope changes?

Comment: yes `this` always refer to current scope, and arrow function do not define a scope, what why `this` then refer in our case to `vue instance`, check this [article](https://medium.com/tfogo/advantages-and-pitfalls-of-arrow-functions-a16f0835799e) for more informations

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `this` reference inside an axios callback function, you can instead define this function in your methods and pass it to axios:

```js
methods: {
  ...
  afterPostRequest(response) {
    console.log(response);
    this.result = response.data;
    console.log('SUCCESS!!');
  },
  handleFileChanges(e) {
    ...
    const afterPostRequest = this.afterPostRequest;
    reader.onload = function oldyfunt(event) {
      ...
      axios.post('http://0.0.0.0:9094/analyze',
        ...
      ).then(afterPostRequest).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('FAILURE!!');
      });
    };
    ...
  },
  ...
},
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I tried to modify the code, and it's still an error. error    'afterPostRequest' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `const afterPostRequest = this.afterPostRequest;` line, I've edited the answer

Comment: when I call this.afterPostRequest, the error related to undefined function gets resolved, but the function doesn't gets triggered because console statements don't print

Comment: I got object destructuring error when I updated code with     const afterPostRequest = this.afterPostRequest;